# Send Intent to Start Activity With String Extras Via ADB

Tags: android-intent, adb

I am trying to see if its possible to simulate a barcode being scanned from the zebra crossing scanner and broadcasting that scan to one of our applications that has the scanner repo built into it.

I have been trying to use adb broadcasts like the folowing:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.package.app.ACTION -es SCAN_RESULT "1021101" com.package.app/.com.package.app.droid.activities.MainActivity
```

With plenty of different variances with no success.

Zebra Crossing Github: https://github.com/zxing/zxing

How the application handles scans

```
  String symbology = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
  String barcode = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
```

Comment: The below answer is correct (and helped me out). Could you please accept it or explain if it didn't fix your problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use either "-e" or "--es" to add a string extra. You've used "-es".

Documentation is here: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#IntentSpec

Comment: This was a big help for me. Thank you!